# Vertical align the checkboxes in a div

Tags: html, css

I am unable to vertical align the checkboxes to middle in a div

I have tried with

```html
<style>

.branding-below {
  bottom: 56px;
  top: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: solid gray 1px!important;
  outline: 0
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40)
  }
}

#onoff+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  position: relative
}

#onoff {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}

#onoff+label::after {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-20px, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background-position: -2px -1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)
}

#onoff:checked+label::after {
  border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
  background-color: rgba(15, 157, 88, .7);
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
}

#onoff:disabled+label::after {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-image: none
}

#onoff+label::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 1.8px;
  height: 1.8px
}

#onoff:focus+label::before {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out
}

#onoff+label::after {
  left: -10px;
  right: auto
}

#onoff+label::before {
  left: -20px;
  /* here offset updated */
  right: auto
}
</style>

<table border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">

<tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
      <div style="align-items: center;height: 75px;padding: 0;align-items: center;border-radius: 2px;line-height: 16px;border: 1px solid;border-color: #bed9b2;">
    <div style="
    display: contents;
">
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Exam</label><br><br>
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Certificate creation</label>
      </div>
    </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display: flex; justify-content: center;` and delete `align-items: center` for the child div of the `td`.
Also, delete `display: contents` for the child of that div element.

```html
<style>
  .branding-below {
    bottom: 56px;
    top: 0
  }
  
  .select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
    border: solid gray 1px!important;
    outline: 0
  }
  
  @keyframes ripple {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0, 0);
      opacity: 1
    }
    20% {
      transform: scale(25, 25);
      opacity: 1
    }
    to {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(40, 40)
    }
  }
  
  #onoff+label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: relative
  }
  
  #onoff {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
  }
  
  #onoff+label::after {
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-20px, -50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    background-position: -2px -1px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)
  }
  
  #onoff:checked+label::after {
    border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
    background-color: rgba(15, 157, 88, .7);
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
  }
  
  #onoff:disabled+label::after {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    background-image: none
  }
  
  #onoff+label::before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    width: 1.8px;
    height: 1.8px
  }
  
  #onoff:focus+label::before {
    animation: ripple 1s ease-out
  }
  
  #onoff+label::after {
    left: -10px;
    right: auto
  }
  
  #onoff+label::before {
    left: -20px;
    /* here offset updated */
    right: auto
  }
</style>

<table border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; height: 75px;padding: 0; border-radius: 2px;line-height: 16px;border: 1px solid;border-color: #bed9b2;"> <!-- Add here -->
        <div> <!-- remove display css -->
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Exam</label><br><br>
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Certificate creation</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need :

```html
<style>

.branding-below {
  bottom: 56px;
  top: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: solid gray 1px!important;
  outline: 0
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40)
  }
}

#onoff+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  position: relative
}

#onoff {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}

#onoff+label::after {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-20px, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background-position: -2px -1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)
}

#onoff:checked+label::after {
  border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
  background-color: rgba(15, 157, 88, .7);
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
}

#onoff:disabled+label::after {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-image: none
}

#onoff+label::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 1.8px;
  height: 1.8px
}

#onoff:focus+label::before {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out
}

#onoff+label::after {
  left: -10px;
  right: auto
}

#onoff+label::before {
  left: -20px;
  /* here offset updated */
  right: auto
}
</style>

<table border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">

<tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center;height: 75px;padding: 0;align-items: center;border-radius: 2px;line-height: 16px;border: 1px solid;border-color: #bed9b2;">
    <div style="">
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Exam</label><br><br>
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Certificate creation</label>
      </div>
    </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align` can be done from the `td` itself :

possible example :

```css
/* update from style removed from HTML */

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;/* whatever height you need (alike min-height for td) */
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #bed9b2;
}
/* end update */


.branding-below {
  bottom: 56px;
  top: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: solid gray 1px!important;
  outline: 0
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40)
  }
}

#onoff+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  position: relative
}

#onoff {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}

#onoff+label::after {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-20px, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background-position: -2px -1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)
}

#onoff:checked+label::after {
  border: 2px solid #0f9d58;
  background-color: rgba(15, 157, 88, .7);
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfgBwEQARzBMMQpAAAAN0lEQVQI12NgQAEHGBgYHzAwMAMxO5DN38AgIM/AYGHHwFBTw8Bg94OBQf4DUBgqzdwAVI5qAACbXgn3nmfmHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
}

#onoff:disabled+label::after {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-image: none
}

#onoff+label::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 1.8px;
  height: 1.8px
}


#onoff:focus+label::before {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out
}

#onoff+label::after {
  left: -10px;
  right: auto
}

#onoff+label::before {
  left: -20px;
  /* here offset updated */
  right: auto
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div  >
        <div>
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Exam</label><br><br>
          <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" style="display:table-column">
          <label for="onoff" style="margin-right: 40px;" class="lbl gray">Turn ON Certificate creation</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```